# Can we measure the amount by which LIGO black hole mergers warp space itself, relative to the mass of the merger?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-gravity, ligo

In our day and age we can calculate the mass and maximum volume of a black hole. With [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) we can also now calculate by how much is space warped, relative to the distance to a black hole merger, such that we could potentially say something like "with a merger of a approximate total mass of M, and an approximate distance from the earth D, we saw a warping of space itself of W", and then even look at the amount of increase in space warping as D approaches 0.

My question then is, do we have anything in quantum mechanics to tell us 2 things:

1. how much space itself (in quantum space theory) warps around a body of mass M
2. how many gravitons are responsible for that amount of warping

Please excuse my lack of knowledge, or if I ask anything silly, I am not a physicist in any way shape or form. My intention was to somewhat get an idea on whether [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328944131_Are_Black_Holes_Actually_Quark_Stars), combined with the answer, can tell us what the quark-to-graviton ratio could be in the universe, since supposedly we could approximate the number of quarks in a black hole.

Comment: gravity is yet not quantized. I would think even if/when  it is the dimensions with respect to h_bar will be such that classical calculations of geodesics will be fine. Also the hypothetical gravitons are bosons, and like photons their number is not conserved.

Comment: We can quantify how much spacetime is warped near a body of mass $M$. We can quantify how much spacetime near Earth is warping when we detect a gravitational wave. None of this requires any quantum mechanics, only classical General Relativity.

Comment: "*we can calculate the mass and maximum volume of a black hole*" - Indeed, see p. 6 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1734 - "*There is zero volume inside the black hole in any Schwarzschild time slice of a Schwarzschild black hole spacetime.*"

Comment: "*how much space itself (in quantum space theory) warps around a body of mass M*" - (1) There is no "quantum space theory".(2) Space doesn't "warp around" a body, but expands in the radial direction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric - "*how many gravitons are responsible for that amount of warping*" - Gravitons have not (and likely will never be) observed experimentally and are not a part of any complete or accepted theory. There is no evidence that gravity has a quantum nature. Your whole question is based on a series of misconceptions.

Comment: Besides, the paper you quote also is based on misconceptions. "*A contradiction exists between the gravitational singularity at the center of a black hole predicted by general relativity and the Pauli exclusion principle*" - No such contradiction exists: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366468 -  Also: "a gravitational singularity [...] having finite mass within a point sized space inside an event horizon*" - This is an urban legend. A singularity is not a point like object in space, but a moment of time along an infinitely long line: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400

Comment: @safesphere that makes sense, thank you for you comments. I understand that there is no evidence that gravity has a quantum nature. However from your answer, 'and likely will never be' it would seem you're not a fan of any theories involving gravitons as carriers of the gravitational force, and I would also love to hear the thoughts of someone who is a fan

Comment: @CosminA. I did not say "never" in relation to gravity's quantum nature. I am totally fine with the idea of quantum gravity. I only said that gravitons likely will never be observed experimentally (even if they exist).They would be just too small to be detected. "*Unambiguous detection of individual gravitons, though not prohibited by any fundamental law, is impossible with any physically reasonable detector*" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton

Comment: @safesphere Oh, right, yes then that makes good sense, I've learned this from many sources and in my limited knowledge I completely agree.

Comment: @safesphere you also said "Your whole question is based on a series of misconceptions.". That makes sense, and I actually am aware of it hehe. But I guess I am still curious as to whether there is any direct correlation between a mass M and the quantifiable impact on space itself. Are there any readings or papers you could suggest, that are even remotely related to this?

Comment: @CosminA. It depends on your level of math. A simple example is the radial Schwarzschild metric: $ d\tau^2 = dt^2\cdot(1-2M/r)-dr^2/(1- 2M/r) $ - This formula shows that near heavy bodies (1) time moves slower and (2) space expands in the radial direction. For example, If I see you 1km from the black hole event horizon, you may see yourself 2km away from it "at the same time". I also would see you moving twice slower while you would see me moving twice faster than yourself. Try posting several narrow questions on this site instead of one broad question.